# Solving PyPSA-EUR using HiGHS

Tags: pypsa, highs

I am trying to solve PyPSA-Eur model using HiGHS solver. I see output like following:

```
 153 fixed variables remaining
 118 fixed variables remaining
 83 fixed variables remaining
 48 fixed variables remaining
 14 fixed variables remaining


   2   7.98e+05 1.43e+04   9.57457108e+12 -3.25361558e+16  5.27e+10   51577s
   3   7.60e+05 1.16e+04   1.50546351e+13 -2.91513709e+16  5.37e+10   63745s

   4   5.68e+05 6.43e+03   2.54314111e+13 -2.26125497e+16  4.77e+10   71036s


   5   2.21e+05 2.66e+03   3.05656310e+13 -1.39062228e+16  2.08e+10  106463s
```

Don't know exactly what to infer from this, how much time it's going to take? Can someone please decipher this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This looks still like the solver is a long way from finishing.

Given the long run-time already, I think you need to downscale the problem size to be able to solve it with HiGHS.

While HiGHS is open-source, it's not as powerful as the commercial Gurobi.

Comment: Thanks for your time. How did you determine that solver is long way from finishing? Also how can problem be scaled down? I am already using cluster size of 37...